# Status of Multitasking in iPad2?

Tags: ipad

iPad 2 has the same OS however a new dual core processor should allow a workaround this limitation and allow for app-switching by freezing whatever apps are inactive at the moment. I ask this question because this is generally how I work...

1. A pdf/djvu file open
2. Mp3 player running
3. Blog being updated
4. Browsing internet

Could someone tell me their experience with such a thing on an iPad? If I switch from a browser to a pdf, does it open in the same page? If I switch back to the browser with a half written blog post, is that preserved or does it refresh? Can a playlist of songs run while I'm doing all this?

I know that its just a tablet and it doesn't promise to be a substitute for netbooks, but this is the way I work even on the go.

On a related note, do SE sites look like [this](http://stackmobile.com/) on an Ipad? I hope there is no problem in rendering Latex/Mathjax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iOS 4.2 and later, both the iPad and iPad 2 will allow multitasking by freezing apps in the background. Some things, such as playing music, will run in the background. Therefore, you will be able to do all of the things you want, but you will only be able to look at one at a time.

No, the SE sites do not look like that. I used the Develop menu in Safari to change the user agent, and it rendered exactly the same for the iPad as for the default view. However, it is different for the iPhone (still not the same as the page you linked).
[image: iPhone Ask Different screenshot]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I am concerned that when an app such as safari freezes, does it lose any dynamic content.. like half written emails, blog posts, stackexchange answers? This question because I suspect that freezing means it would reload the webpage when I switch apps and return to the browser.

Comment: When it is frozen, the app will store its current state, meaning it should be the same when you come back. However, Safari will reload the page if you are gone for more than a few minutes. This is because Apple designed it that way, and not because of the freezing.

Comment: Not necessarily -- Safari will keep a webpage in memory until that memory is needed by another app. Only *then* will it reload the page when you come back to it. I've left webpages open on Safari only to come back to them the next day; they were still in memory so it just displayed them as they were when I last had Safari open.

Comment: @Brant I guess that's your experience. In mine, it reloads the page if I haven't looked at it in the past few minutes, even if I was still in Safari but looking at a different page. Sometimes it reloads from cache instead of actually reloading, but it still causes it to get rid of form content.